# How to I use the MAX function in power bi only on the filtered records?

Tags: filter, max, powerbi, dax

I am trying to select the record with the latest date, all of the records in the database have these basic columns AssetNumber, WorkOrderNumber, ScheduledEndDate, Department

I want to find all the latest work order "date" for each asset in a specific department. I have a basic measure and column to do this but it is not working.

How do I filter the records and then apply the max date function. I have tried using ALL, ALLEXCEPT, ALLSELECTED etc.

```
| ASSET | DEPARTMENT | WOSCHED_ENDDATE |
|-------|------------|-----------------|
| 2160  | 57257E     | 11/29/2011      |
| 2160  | 57257E     | 7/28/2014       |
| 6440  | 57257E     | 3/5/2012        |
| 6440  | 57257E     | 3/9/2015        |
```

At the basic level I need to remove the two records with the old dates from my visual. I can find the most recent (MAX) date of the entire column but I cannot get the MAX function to work in the context of the filtered values which by department like I have in the sample grid.

Thank you

Comment: Show the expressions you have tried. Also explain how you are filtering the data.

Comment: Measure-- MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Data_Mart'[WOSCHED_ENDDATE].[Date]), VALUES('Data_Mart'[ASSET])) The Column is as follows, IsLast = if(maxDate = (data_Mart[WOSCHED_ENDDATE].DATE]), "IS LAST",''))

Comment: I am trying to filter using the slicer on the report page. This should be very simple, I just want the max function to filter in the context of the slicer.

Comment: I have used this link as the basis of my approach, this works fine in the context of the entire table, but I cannot figure out how to reduce the records that the max function is looking at. I hope this helps.

Comment: In your example you filter 57257E department and you should get the max  enddate for that department but currently you are getting the max enddate for the column. right?

Comment: yes instead of getting the max WOSCHED_ENDATE for the filtered rows only (in the department) the expression is returning the max for the entire column of WOSCHED_ENDATE

Comment: Are you adding WOSCHED_ENDATE column to the Values table? If so delete it from there leaving only ASSET and DEPARTMENT column, then create a measure `MaxDate=MAX(WOSCHED_ENDATE)` and add it to the values table. See my answer update.

Comment: @alejandro zuleta That gets me the max date for the filtered context which is great! Thank you very much. I will mark this as complete. Is there a way to have this evaluate the expression by asset number? I would like to see what the last date is for each asset number. Thank you!

Comment: @alejandrozuleta ok, thank you again, I figured out what the issue was, if a column has multiple values for each asset number your method was retuning the max for each asset and (column type etc.) this is ok, I can just filter out to the ones I need specifically. Anyway thank you for your time and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a measure:

```
MaxDate =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Data_Mart'[WOSCHED_ENDDATE] ),
    ALLSELECTED ( 'Data_Mart'[WOSCHED_ENDDATE] )
)
```

I think the simple:

`MaxDate = MAX( 'Data_Mart'[WOSCHED_ENDDATE] )` should work.

In Power BI using a matrix I get:

[image]

Note `WOSCHED_ENDDATE` is not included in the matrix if you include it the measure will be evaluated per each row so the MaxDate measure will give the same date in each row.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: When I use that formula I evaluates the max date for each record and either selects all records or eliminates all records. What I need to fugure out is how to find the max date for each group of records by asset number. Thank you!

Comment: @user3094203, What visualization are you using? Also what column are you filtering in the slicer?

Comment: I am just using the table visualization. I am filtering by the department column,  I want to be able to have the measure determine the max value per set of asset numbers and the column to compare the measure against each record and determine if the record is = to the measure if it is equal then it should flag it if not then do nothing. In my mind I need to filter the table to the department level, then group the records by asset then filter out everything older than the most recent record per asset group. Then I will be left with the list of most current work orders.

Comment: @user3094203, could you add a basic example of your data and the expected result.

Comment: @user3094203, edit your question and include sample data and expected results there comments are not intended to that.