# Power BI MAX function is not affected by visual filter

Tags: powerbi

I've got a table with trades with fields `Currency`, `NetProfit`. I need to display the maximum profitable trade `MAX(NetProfit)` for all the trades or eventually for one or more currency selected. I've created a Measure:

```
Largest win = MAX('public Historic'[NetProfit])
```

and I dragged the measure to a visual card.

Example. The behavior should be as follows:

```
TradeID  Currency    net_profit
------------------------------
1        EURUSD       200
1        EURUSD        80
1        USDJPY       -90
1        USDJPY         2
1        USDJPY       150
```

I've got a slicer with Currency

```
Values

EURUSD
USDJPY
```

With no currency selected

```
MAX(NetProfit) = 200
```

But with USDJPY selected, `MAX(NetProfit)` should be 150, but that is not happening and keeps showing 200

This works for average though.

Comment: Did you click on the small filter icon on top/bottom of the visualization to check if the filter is being applied?

Comment: Click on your Slicer, then in the ribbon go to the Format in Visual Tools. Then click Edit Interactions, and see that it is properly being applied to your visual. Also confirm you're using `Max` and not `Maxx` which ignores filters. [You can try this method too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514584/how-to-i-use-the-max-function-in-power-bi-only-on-the-filtered-records)

Comment: CR7SMS, Thanks, yes I checked it and the filter is being applied on the visual

Comment: Hello Mark S. Thanks for the reply, yes is checked and is Ok. I've tried both with a Measure and Also dragging the field to the card and in the Fields slot, selecting Maximum, and nothing happens.

Comment: The curious thing is that I do the same in a different card using count and works. The version is Version: 2.76.5678.782 64-bit (December 2019)

Comment: Gents ... I found the issue it was not PowerBI. The issue was between the chair and the keyboard (me). The data range, regardless the filters, is [-30, 29] for both the currencies so will always show those values. Thanks for the answers and sorry for making you waste your time.

Comment: @MarcelloChiuminatto I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate? This may be useful for someone else who encounters the problem. Maybe post your own answer and mark it as answered?

Comment: @Marks, sure. This is a data issue that I didn't see. I was trying to display the maximum and minimum value for a field named NetProfit, which  have values for two different classes (Curreny pairs).

Comment: Sure, see the next Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marks, sure. This is a data issue that I didn't see. I was trying to display the maximum and minimum value for a field named NetProfit, which  have values for two different classes (Currency pairs).

This was the case

Currency    NetProfit
EURUSD     -30.5
EURUSD     29.0
EURUSD     29.0
EURUSD     12.0
EURUSD     -15.0
EURUSD     -30.5
USDJPY     -17.5
USDJPY     29.0
USDJPY     12.0
USDJPY     -30.5
USDJPY     -15.0
USDJPY     -30.5

I had a visual slicer from Currency column so the values were:

ALL
EURUSD
USDJPY

I had a card displaying

MAX(NetProfit)
MIN(NetProfit)

The thing is that no matter the Currency (ALL, EURUSD, USDJPY) I selected in the slicer, MAX will always be 29.0 and MIN will always be -30.5.

Since I didn't pay attention to data range and visually the values for MAX and MIN were not changing I thought there was an issue with PowerBI, but it wasn't. The PowerBI behavior was Ok.